# AngularJS not working with Flask

Tags: python, angularjs

I have this [simple app](http://codehandbook.org/angularjs-not-working-in-python-flask-web-app/):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>working app</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('myApp', [])
            .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                $scope.message = "Howdy!!";
            }])
            .config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider) {
                    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{a');
                    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('a}');
            }]);
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
<h1>Hello!</h1>
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <span>{message}</span>
        <span>{{ '{{message}}' }}</span>
    </div>


</body>
```

I'm getting `{message} {{message}}` in `html` page not scope value. I don't have any idea, where I'm going wrong. I really appreciate any sort of help in this!

Comment: what is the error in your console ?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? And why have you put `{{ '{{message}}' }}` - what is that supposed to be?

Comment: @Naga Sai: I'm not getting any error in my console.

Comment: @DanielRoseman:  I'm getting, {message} {{message}} in my html page, not scope value.

Comment: Yes. Why are you using this bizarre syntax, instead of Angular's actual syntax?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Because I'm servering this page with Flask. Flask also uses {{}}

Comment: But firstly, you've changed your angular syntax to `{a ... a}`, and second that still doesn't give any reason for wrapping a string inside Jinja tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve your expected result, use below option to bind your scope value

{a message a}
Start tag and end tag should be '{a' and 'a}' respectively without {{}} inside them

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>working app</title>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
<h1>Hello!</h1>
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

        <span>{a message a}</span>
    </div>


</body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
            .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                $scope.message = "Howdy!!";
            }])
            .config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider) {
                    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{a');
                    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('a}');
            }]);
```

Codepen= http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JKrVgV

Comment: Thanks! Understood my mistake :)