# AngularJS $scope not showing value

Tags: angularjs

I'm using flask(version `1.0.2`) and AngularJS (version `1.7.2`) material (version `1.1.10`).

Problem is the controller is attached to view and it working, but just **not showing value in view**.

The controller

```
$$.controller("bigLayoutToolbarController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.title = "---"
    console.log(">>", $scope.title)
})
```

Surprisingly the console logging is working.

```
>> ---
```

The view

```
<section layout="row" flex style="height: 100%" ng-controller="bigLayoutToolbarController">
<h2 flex md-truncate>{{ title }}</h2>
</section>
```

What am i wrong?

Comment: as i see nothing is wrong, can you show the full code?

Comment: @Sajeetharan That is almost full code bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the md-truncate because  it will will automatically clip text which is wider than the component.

**`DEMO`**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller("bigLayoutToolbarController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.title = "---"
    console.log(">>", $scope.title)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<section layout="row" flex style="height: 100%" ng-controller="bigLayoutToolbarController">
<h2 flex md-truncate>{{ title }}</h2>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: it should work unless if you are doing some other mistake. see the demo

Comment: yea i know it must be work. but i don't know why it happens

Comment: try to reproduce your issue with plunker, i am sure something wrong with your code

Comment: Sajeetharan, you're using the wrong version of angularjs. not sure if this actually matters.

Comment: what is the version you are using

Comment: AngularJS version is 1.7.2

Comment: yea i tried downgrade AngularJS version to 1.6.9 just a min ago. but it still not showing. I will check again

Comment: why you are using $$.controller?

Comment: because $$ is angular module value. just like that `var $$ = angular.module("kangnamAddons", ['ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngMaterial'])`

Comment: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38415171/angularjs-not-working-with-flask)